# Define enums in Hibernate entities as constant string

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Is it acceptable to have enums defined as constants in Hibernate entities and use them through the code?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table", schema = "", catalog = "")
public class Table {

    @Transient
    public static final String STATUS_PENDING = "PENDING";
    @Transient
    public static final String STATUS_ACCEPTED = "ACCEPTED";
    @Transient
    public static final String STATUS_REJECTED = "REJECTED";

    private String status;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 8)
    public String getStatus() {
         return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
         this.status = status;
    }
}
```

And then I can use them:

```
if(status.equals(Table.STATUS_PENDING) {
     entityObject.setStatus(Table.STATUS_PENDING);
}
```

Of Course I can define enum class and use it, but what about this approach?

Comment: Why not? I don't see any restrictions to this...

Comment: Has nothing to do with your question, but `@Transient` is not necessary for static fields.

Comment: JPA's @Transient annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database. So it is very much to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the class Table only as a DTO, this is good enough.

If you want to use it both as a DTO and DAO , then you need to add @JsonIgnore along with the @Transient